# How to programmatically clone a layer of MapBox?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm loading a style with an existing `CircleLayer` and I'd like to programmatically add another such layer with similar styling (say, same except different color).  Its geo data will be created programatically as well.

I could not find an easy API for cloning a layer.

But even if I do something like:

```
CircleLayer oldLayer, newLayer = ...;
newLayer.withProperties(
    PropertyFactory.circleColor(Color.parseColor("#e55e5e")),
    oldLayer.getCircleStrokeColor()
);
```

Setting circle color (as a literal) works but for setting stroke color (taken from the other layer) I'm getting:

```
09-25 20:59:20.783 18014-18014/com.example.client E/mbgl: {example.client}[JNI]: Error setting property: circle-stroke-color property not found
```

I checked, `oldLayer` is properly initialized and `oldLayer.getCircleStrokeColor()` does return a proper `PropertyValue`.  What am I missing?